# SQL query result assertion

Tags: c#, sql

I have put together the following method:

```
public static ArrayList DbQueryToArry()
        {
            string SqlCString = "connString";
            SqlConnection connection = null;

            ArrayList valuesList = new ArrayList();

            connection = new SqlConnection(SqlCString);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select CLIENTNO, ACCOUNT_Purpose from audit.ACCOUNTS_AUDIT", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                valuesList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[0]));
            }
            return valuesList;
        }
```

I'd like to be able to run an assertion like this one:

```
var a = DbQueryToArry();         
Assert.IsTrue(a.Contains("some value"));
```

Given reader [0]

```
valuesList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[0]));
```

I only get the first column (`CLIENTINFO`) into the array and not the second (ACCOUNT_Purpose). How should I modify the code to get both ?

In addition, the returned values could be either a String or Int so would my current code version should be handling both ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `valuesList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[0]));` is where you get ClientInfo,  you need to add `reader[1]` to your valuesList to include Account_Purpose

Comment: How, exactly, could a column be of different types? The only time I've seen that was due to a *problem* with an expression in a view, where the column was either `float` or `decimal(18,4)` depending on whether or not any rows hit a CASE condition that caused the latter type to be yielded and then all rows were up-converted. Is `audit.ACCOUNTS_AUDIT` a view with complex expressions for those columns?

Comment: Column 'CLIENTINFO' returns int and Column 'ACCOUNT_Purpose' returns string. I would to have both in an array and be able to make an assertion on whether a specific int or string is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we switch from *obsolete* `ArrayList` to something like `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> DbQueryToArray(string sql) {
  if (null == sql)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sql));

  //TODO: do not hardcode connetcion string but read it (say, from Settings)
  string SqlCString = "connString";

  //DONE: Wrap IDisposable into using
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SqlCString)) {
    connection.Open();

    //DONE: Wrap IDisposable into using
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection)) {
      //DONE: Wrap IDisposable into using
      using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
          yield return reader as IDataRecord;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then you can use *Linq* in order to query the `result`:

```
 var a = DbQueryToArray("Select CLIENTNO, ACCOUNT_Purpose from audit.ACCOUNTS_AUDIT");

 Assert.IsTrue(a.Any(record => 
   Convert.ToString(record["CLIENTNO"]) == "some value")); 

 Assert.IsTrue(a.Any(record => 
   Convert.ToString(record["ACCOUNT_Purpose"]) == "some other value"));
```

If you don't want execute query several times, you can *materialize* the results:

```
 var a = DbQueryToArray("Select CLIENTNO, ACCOUNT_Purpose from audit.ACCOUNTS_AUDIT")
   .ToList();

 Assert.IsTrue(a.Any(record => Convert.ToString(record[0]) == "some value")); 

 Assert.IsTrue(a.Any(record => Convert.ToString(record[1]) == "some other value"));
```

Finally (see comments below), if we want to test if *any* field in *any* record has the value:

```
  var a = DbQueryToArray("Select CLIENTNO, ACCOUNT_Purpose from audit.ACCOUNTS_AUDIT")
    .SelectMany(line => {
      // Flatten the cursor into IEnumerable<String>
      string[] result = new string[line.FieldCount];

      for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i)
        result[i] = Convert.ToString(line[i]);

      return result;
    });

  a.Any(item => item == "some value");
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitry, but in both case I need to specify either the column name or index..I would like to run an assertion on the list regardless of many columns the query returns  as I may use a different query next time with different columns names or overall number or columns...

Comment: @entrup: So you want to check if *any* column (no matter which) and *any* record has a value?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I only care about wheather a value exists in any of the columns.

Comment: Excellent, that's highly appreciated. LINQ is by far the better way to go and allows m to make additional assertions. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It is because you only read the first value of the reader. `Reader.Read()` read each row one by one and `Convert.ToString(reader[0]))` means that you want to read the first column as string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataTable` and `SqlDataAdapter` to get query result in form of table. Something like this:

```
string connString = @"your connection string here";
string query = "select * from table";
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);        
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
conn.Open();
// create data adapter
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
// this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
da.Fill(dataTable);
conn.Close();
da.Dispose();
```

Then you can use `dataTable` object to see if particular values exist.

Comment: Thanks Michal, where is 'dataTable' declared in your code ?

Comment: @entrup Added necessary declararion

Comment: Thanks  Michal. I've ran the code but it does not seen to return any values...Tried Assert.IsTrue(dataTable.ToString().Contains("Some value")); with no success.

Answer (score 0):

That's cause you are getting only the first column. You can do something like below by specifying the column name

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            valuesList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["CLIENTNO"]));
            valuesList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader["ACCOUNT_Purpose"]));
        }
```

Moreover, since you are converting all the columns to `string`; I would suggest to use a strongly typed collection like `List<string>` rather then `ArrayList valuesList = new ArrayList();`

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but the whole point is not needing to specify the columns..but to to iterated through them..So if more columns added, the code still works..

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, However some concerns

1. Lets stop using `ArrayList`, and use a `List<T>` instead
2. Lets use a `using` statement where you can

<sub>***Note*** : I have used a `ValueTuple` to return more than 1 field</sub>

**Example**

```
public static List<(string clientNo, string account)> DbQueryToArray()
{
   const string SqlCString = "connString";

   var valuesList = new List<(string clientNo, string account)>();

   using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SqlCString))
   {
      connection.Open();

      using (var command = new SqlCommand("Select CLIENTNO, ACCOUNT_Purpose from audit.ACCOUNTS_AUDIT", connection))
      {
         var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

         while (reader.Read())
            valuesList.Add(((string)reader[0],(string)reader[1]) );
      }
   }
   return valuesList;
}
```

**Usage**

```
var results = DbQueryToArray();
Assert.IsTrue(results.Any(x => x.clientNo == someValue || x.account == someValue));
```

Comment: Thanks again Michael. That would work but I'm aiming towards a more generic code that is able to handle different sql queries. I would like the code to be robust and able to handle different number of columns. The way it's written fits only a query that returns 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

best practice is to check first if the reader has rows

```
reader.HasRows
```

then close the reader and the connection

your code should look like this:

```
public static ArrayList DbQueryToArry()
    {
        string SqlCString = "connString";
        SqlConnection connection = null;

        ArrayList valuesList = new ArrayList();

        connection = new SqlConnection(SqlCString);
        using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select CLIENTNO, ACCOUNT_Purpose from audit.ACCOUNTS_AUDIT", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    valuesList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[0]));
                    valuesList.Add(Convert.ToString(reader[1])); // add to valuelist
                }
            }

            reader.Close(); // close reader

        } //dispose connection

        return valuesList;
    }
```